OAuth2 Token Fails to Grant Access to YouTube Analytics API Despite Correct Scopes
Our app was recently validated by Google and uses YouTube APIs to access both YouTube Analytics and YouTube Data. The necessary APIs are correctly enabled in the project, and we are using the following OAuth scopes in our OAuth 2.0 requests:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner
Access tokens are being successfully generated after the app's validation.

Issue:
When attempting to access the YouTube Analytics API, we consistently receive a 403 Forbidden error. The same authenticated user is able to access the YouTube Data API without any issues, but attempts to access YouTube Analytics data fail due to a permission issue. The app is set to production, and the APIs are active.
Actions Taken:
We revoked the access token and reconnected the account to ensure the new token includes the necessary scope above.
The OAuth configuration has been reviewed, and the app's status is marked as "in production".
Google Cloud logs do not provide any additional information regarding the 403 error.
We tested the YouTube Analytics API Explorer, which resulted in the same error.
The authenticated user has the correct permissions and is the owner of the YouTube channel.
We could not view or remove the test users in the OAuth configuration screen in the Google Cloud Console, but since the app is in production, this should not interfere.
